# WebdriverIO typescript cannot find name $(dollar sign)

Tags: typescript, e2e-testing, webdriver-io

I am writing e2e tests using webdriverio and mocha, I am using `typescript` to code

However, when I compile I get a bunch of error because of the dollar sign `$` of browser.execute

example of code:

```
injetarTextoPropriedade(seletor) {
    browser.execute(function () {
        $(seletor).each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.attr("conteudo", $this.text().trim());
        });
    });
}
```

and then, when I compile, I get the following error:

`src/pages/page.ts(42,4): error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Is `$()` jquery? You need `npm i -D @types/jquery`?

Answer (score 4):

**If you're using WebdriverIO you don't have to install jQuery types to properly compile $ in TypeScript.**

This functions are declared in main webdriverIO module:
node_modules/@wdio/sync/webdriverio.d.ts:

(this is how end of the file looks like, just for reference):

```
/**
 * find a single element on the page.
 */
declare function $(selector: string | Function): WebdriverIO.Element;

/**
 * find multiple elements on the page.
 */
declare function $$(selector: string | Function): WebdriverIO.ElementArray;

declare module "@wdio/sync" {
    export = WebdriverIO
}
```

If you're using @wdio/sync (or async, it doesn't make any difference here) just make sure you have the right version in your dependencies in package.json and try to reinstall your node_modules with simple ***npm i*** or yarn, whichever you use.

If the error is still there you probably made some mistakes during the setup.
Try to check all the steps from here: https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript

Answer (score 0):

Although OP accepted an answer, I feel other people(like myself) may be looking for another similar issue.

If you the error `Cannot find name '$'` happens for the webdriverio `$` instead of JQuery `$`, you can work around by declare `$` globally.

Add a file and name it `global.d.ts` and `declare const $, $$;`

Not pretty though, let me know if you have a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have proper import statement to import $.

Following is the import statement
`import { $ } from '@wdio/globals';`